# My Flex 3 Website Doesn't Have Any Keywords Listed in Google's Webmaster Tools

Tags: google-search-console, keywords

I've got a Flex 3 website. When I in Google's webmaster tools -> Your site on the web -> Keywords, none are listed.

Does anyone have an all-Flex site that has keywords listed for it the above? The sites been up for about a month. It's been indexed by Google. I have keyword metatags in the site, which from what I've read Google ignores.

Where does google come up with the keywords for your site? Any suggestions on what I need to do?

Thank you.

-Laxmidi

[www.brainpinata.com](http://www.brainpinata.com)

Answer (score 2):

The keywords field doesn't list your meta tag for keywords. It lists the most used keywords that referred to your site from Google. It is possible that you just don't have any referrers yet, hence there is nothing to show.

Answer (score 1):

Google is not great at indexing the content from Flash files, but [it is getting better](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2008/06/improved-flash-indexing.html). I don't know of any particular techniques to get your Flash content indexed better but you should do some research and see if you can change your Flash code to improve indexing.

Answer (score 0):

Google's keywords list keywords found on your website. It is no keywords at you site, because the only code in your site is a javascript which calls the flash. And Google cannot read flash.

Google often ignore the meta tags.

Flash is bad for SEO.

Comment: Flash is bad for SEO. However, Google does index Flash content now.

Comment: Google now lists some keywords for my site. Although the top words are: failed, endpoint, amf, faulstring, play, cat, etc. I'm concerned that "failed" is the top word. I don't see any problems on the site. I'm hoping that Googlebot isn't running into an error. Thanks.